# ruby_block conditional statement and waiting for reboot

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I got some great direction from coderanger on chef IRC and I didn't want to bug him further but here's my problem:

My goal is to run recipe one, then two, then reboot while keeping the chef run alive, then execute recipe three. I think I'm close but still running into errors. I'm not sure if it's my code block or the way Windows behaves.

Here's my code block:

```
ruby_block "test" do
  block do
    run_context.include_recipe "stuff::reboot"
        while reboot_pending? == true do
            run_context.include_recipe "stuff::three"
     end
  end
end
```

The block executes with no issue but it seems to move on quickly to the stuff::three recipe which causes this error because powershell isn't available since the machine is still booting up:

```
==> default: The argument 'c:/tmp/vagrant-elevated-shell.ps1' to the -File parameter does not exist. Provide the path to an existing '.ps1' file as an argument to the -File parameter.
```

I'm thinking that once the reboot command is issued, after a few seconds there is no longer a pending reboot. So, is there a different ruby helper to use my while with? Or is this block just crap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sooooo I answer a lot of the questions here too. Thanks for the thought though.

You keep trying to put the `include_recipe` in the body of the while loop, which isn't what you want I don't think. That says "include this over and over while a reboot is pending".

What you want is this:

```
include_recipe 'stuff::reboot'

ruby_block 'wait for reboot' do
  block do
    true while reboot_pending?
  end
end

include_recipe 'stuff::three'
```

That will put a resource in the collection between the stuff from the two recipes that halts the converge if a reboot is pending, otherwise it continues.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. I tried the code above and the same behavior exists. There's a slight pause when the reboot portion executes and then the run continues and then fails.

Comment: Ok, i think i got it figured out. I wrote a recipe to reboot the windows server and i guess it wasnt using the reboot pending handler so I enabled the windows reboot_handler and it worked with the exception of "Default value "60" is invalid for property timeout of resource windows_reboot. In Chef 13 this will become an error: Option timeout must be a kind of [Integer]!  You passed "60".. at 1 location:" THANK YOU SO MUCH!